# Visual-Studio-Python-: Debugger speedups using cython not found

Tags: python, visual-studio

I am brand new to Python and Visual Studio, but keep getting this error when running in debug mode. I had Python 3.7 installed and it looks like Visual Studio installed Python 3.6. I am wondering if this is part of the issue.

> warning: Debugger speedups using cython not found. Run '"C:\Program
>   Files\python.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python\Core\Packages\ptvsd\pydevd\setup_cython.py"
>   build_ext --inplace' to build. pydev debugger: starting

Answer (score 0):

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and Python  and was having the same issue. I managed to get rid of the error by going to Tools->Options->Python->Experimental and ticking off 'Use experimental debugger', then shutting down and restarting Visual Studio. It is early days so far but the

> warning: Debugger speedups using cython not found. Run '"C:\Program Files\python.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python\Core\Packages\ptvsd\pydevd\setup_cython.py" build_ext --inplace' to build. pydev debugger: starting

is gone now.